# Why is there an extra empty row when splited by multibyte punctuation?

Tags: php, split, multibyte

Try this:

```
$pattern = '/[\x{ff0c},]/u';

//$string = "something here ; and there, oh,that's all!";
$string = 'hei,nihao，a ';


echo '<pre>', print_r( preg_split( $pattern, $string ), 1 ), '</pre>';
exit();
```

output:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => hei,nihao，a
)
</pre>
```

Comment: Instead of just working on the previous question you asked, you started another one that is more a comment to someone's answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452777/how-to-split-a-string-by-multiple-delimiters-in-php

Comment: Oh there are always pros and cons.I'm sure some one is glad that I did so.But obviously someone is not.What should I do?Where should I go?

Answer (score 0):

The character you have is a fullwidth comma ( hex ff0c ), as well as a regular comma. Have you tried updating it to my version which accounts for it?

```
<?php
$pattern = '/[\x{ff0c},]/u';

//$string = "something here ; and there, oh,that's all!";
$string = 'hei,nihao，a ';


echo '<pre>', print_r( preg_split( $pattern, $string ), 1 ), '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hei
    [1] => nihao
    [2] => a 
)
```

Comment: In the other prior post you said you updated it to be like mine. Did you have it *exactly* like mine? If so paste the new exact version that I had please.

Comment: I tried your code,and the output is not the same as yours.It's <pre>Array
(
    [0] => hei,nihao，a
)
</pre>

Comment: *sigh*

Can you update your post with my updated version so I can see? You may have made some mistake and missed something, there is a 'u' character after the regex that you may have missed if you copied it manually, which is why I want to see what you have *now*

Comment: Ok. Mine is still giving me the same result. What php version do you have? It's possible yours may not support the unicode inside the regex character set.

Comment: And just curious, how did you generate that character in the first place? You're dealing with a language other than English?

Comment: Yes,it's CJK character.I'm gonna give it up,by replace that special character.

Comment: PHP 5.2.5 (cli) (built: Nov  8 2007 23:18:51)