# In PHP, how can I split a string by whitespace, commas, and newlines at the same time

Tags: php, arrays, split, explode, delimiter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to split a string by multiple delimiters in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452777/how-to-split-a-string-by-multiple-delimiters-in-php)

What would be the most efficient way to split a string by three delimiters at the same time, specifically a single white space, newline, and commas?

Comment: @GabrielSantos Good point. Welcome Michael!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since you've tagged your questions with `php` I will stick to that. See **[`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)**

```
$split_strings = preg_split('/[\ \n\,]+/', $your_string);
```

This will keep the array clean too, in case your string is something like `some, ,,string`, it will still result in `['some', 'string']` instead of `['some', '', '', '', 'string']`.

Comment: What about incorporating an escape character? `hey 'this is' some text` yielding `['hey', 'this is', 'some', 'text']`?

Comment: Depending on the operating system it can be useful to add the return character, so it would be like $split_strings = preg_split('/[\ \n\r\,]+/', $your_string); (added \r after \n)

Comment: Also, to avoid "empty strings" to be returned on the array, you should use `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` on the flags parameter, so it would be like `preg_split('/[\ \n\r\,]+/', $your_string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`, as told in: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: Why note `explode(' ', $my_string)`?