# Split string by multiple (more specific) delimiters in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, split

I know this question has been asked a million times, though I can't really find the answer for my question.

I read the answer from this question [How to split a string by multiple delimiters in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452777/how-to-split-a-string-by-multiple-delimiters-in-php)

Which looks fine, however I'm not sure about what pattern I should use when I want to use delimiters like:

- " & "
- " feat "
- " vs. "

it's important for the spaces to be included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/\s*(&|feat|vs\.)\s*/` as pattern.

- `/XYZ|ABC/` matches `XYZ` or `ABC`.

See [Alternation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.alternation.php) from PHP PCRE regex syntax.

Comment: Doh! guess 20 hours of beeing awake took it's toll, stupid I didn't came up with this. Thank you so much!