# Check if PHP string contains operation characters

Tags: php, regex, string, substring, contains

I want to check it a sting has any of operations for calculations ex:

```
$str = "part1+part2"
```

Check if **$str** contains any of those characters: **+**, **-**, **/**, or *****

Then assign each part of the sting to a variable

```
$p1 = "part1";
$p2 = "part2";
$opr = "+";
```

Comment: You can use [`preg_split()`](http://de1.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-split.php) function.

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452777/how-to-split-a-string-by-multiple-delimiters-in-php

Comment: Is there anything you have tried? Where is your problem?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: why is this too broad! reopen this question, dang it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a regex that would work. I've also done the actual calculation too, which you may or may not need.

The regex looks for anything before a +-/or *, and calls it var1, then it finds an operator, and then var2. Play with the regex here https://regex101.com/r/fXw0cv/2

Check this:

```
<?php

$x = "50+60";
$regex = '#(?<val1>.*)(?<operator>[\+\-\/\*])(?<val2>.*)#';

preg_match( $regex, $x, $match);

if (count($match)) {
    echo $match['val1'] . $match['operator'] . $match['val2'] .' = ';
    switch ($match['operator']) {
        case '+':
            $result = $match['val1'] + $match['val2'];
            break;
        case '-':
            $result = $match['val1'] - $match['val2'];
            break;
        case '/':
            $result = $match['val1'] / $match['val2'];
            break;
        case '*':
            $result = $match['val1'] * $match['val2'];
            break;
    }
    echo $result;
}
```

> Output: 50+60 = 110 https://3v4l.org/LS2pB